# Workaround for abstract AND static method in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, static-methods, abstract

Our framework / rules engine defines a Flow as an atomic sequence where a user is asked a question and then his or her results are interpreted, most often resulting in transition to a subsequent flow for more questions and processing.  For reuse purposes, we have a pattern we call "isNeeded", where a static method hangs off a Flow class, letting other Flows know if its needed at any point in a sequence through the application.  For example, a "Process Payment Flow" might have an isNeeded method like this:

```
  public static boolean isNeeded() {
    ReasonTracker rt;
    if (User has payment due) {
       rt = new ReasonTracker(ProcessPaymentFlow.class, true, "payment due");
    } else {
       rt = new ReasonTracker(ProcessPaymentFlow.class, false, "no payment due");
    }
    return rt.isNeeded();
  }
```

So, if you're anywhere in the application and want to see if the user should be given the ProcessPaymentFlow, you can call the isNeeded() method and then send the user in where appropriate.  Furthermore, there is logging so we can figure out why certain users hit a particular flow and others do not.

Now, as a modification to our framework, I'm trying to standardize the use of this method.  In my head, there is a final static "isNeeded()" method that calls an overridable **abstract** static "isNeededInner()" method, where one can define the cases, logging, and results, in an OO-enforceable way.  However!  I do recognize that this is a contradictory concept.

Without resorting to hacks / trickery, IS there a way to mimic the concept of an abstract static method in Java, or am I constrained by the way we've thought this up, so far?  Bonus - Is there some way to work in this or super with getClass() to avoid manually inserting the class name for logging?

Comment: Who decides which implementation of `isNeededInner()` should be called? Without more details this more sounds like a feature toggle not like an abstract method.

Comment: Why are you using a static method in the first place? This sounds more like a Polymorphic problem to me, which would easily be done when using normal Instances

Comment: This seems too broad to give an answer other than “avoid static methods for this, and use a dependency injection framework”.

Comment: Yeah, there are other ways to cover this functionality, but instantiating one of these objects "means something different" in the Framework; whereas doing this statically does not.

Comment: @IVRAvenger then again you have a design flaw, split these functionalities up if they have different behavior. Else you'll end up with a mess, like right now. Better invest some time to split it up, to make it then easier in the future